# OBIEE server WSDL importing issue in SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui, soap-client, obiee

OBIEE server WSDL url is  http://mysrvr:port/analytics/saw.dll?wsdl

From browser, When i hit above wsdl url from browser it will ask for credentials and then wsdl showed up. 
[image]

but when i try to import same wsdl from SAOPUI, it will through error

> WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://mysrvr:port/analytics/saw.dll?wsdl'.:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The declaration for the entity
>   "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.

In Java, wsimport is also giving similar kind of error.

> [ERROR] The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with
>   '>'.   line 31 of http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd
>
> [ERROR] The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with
>   '>'.
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document:
>   http://13.91.61.102:9502/analytics/saw.dll?wsdl, because 1) could not
>   find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root
>   element of the document is not .
>
> [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided
>   WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be
>   provided.
>
> ```
>     Failed to parse the WSDL.
> ```

**Things are pretty straight, if we hit url, it is returning html content not wsdl content. but my doubt here is why?

and how can i import WSDL in SOAPUI tool in this situation?**

Generally with other OBIEE servers, I am not facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer, My OBIEE server has enabled some kind of SSO authentication. which redirect http request to http://mysrvr:port/bi-security-login/login.jsp?redirect=asdjkkjjd.....

It has something to do with Siteminder SSO in OBIEE 12c, may be in this server siteminder sso is not working which leads to redirecting url and get authenticate.
For more information on Siteminder SSO in OBIEE 12c 

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Enterprise%20Performance%20Management%20and%20Business%20Intelligence/2185055_1.html

In this case we need to bypass siteminder sso, slight changes in URL
http://mysrvr:port/analytics-ws/saw.dll?wsdl 
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The actual wsdl sits at ...saw.dll/wsdl/v12 for 12.2.1.3 for example